# How to get the angle (pitch/yaw) between two 3D vectors for an autoaim

Tags: c++, math, unity-game-engine, trigonometry, algebra

I'm trying to get the angles between two vectors (My Camera Position and Enemy Position) to create an autoaim/aimbot.

The game is Unity based, it uses the left handed coordinate system. X Y Z is right, up, forward.

The game also uses degrees.

Here is the pseudocode I am trying but its failing to give me the proper pitch/yaw.

```
diff = camera_position - enemy_position
hypotenuse = sqrt(diff.x*diff.x + diff.y*diff.y)

angle.x = asinf(diff.z / hypotenuse) * (180 / PI);
angle.y = atan2(diff.y / diff.x) * (180 / PI);
angle.z = 0.0f;
```

Can someone help me with this? I am terrible at math.

Comment: Are the angles in the world space, or local to the player?

Comment: You say it is a library so not using unity engine. Then maybe http://m.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the angles between two vectors (My Camera Position
>   and Enemy Position)

**In Unity**:

Use the `Angle` function from `Vector3` structure.

```
float angle = Vector3.Angle(camera_position, enemy_position);
```

Or Individual angles:

```
float angleX = Vector3.Angle(new Vector3(camera_position.x, 0, 0), new Vector3(enemy_position.x, 0, 0));
float angleY = Vector3.Angle(new Vector3(0, camera_position.y, 0), new Vector3(0, enemy_position.y, 0));
float angleZ = Vector3.Angle(new Vector3(0, 0, camera_position.z), new Vector3(0, 0, enemy_position.z));
```

**EDIT**:

> I'm not using the Unity engine. This is a separate module I am
>   creating to rig my own autoaim. I'm trying to do get the proper math
>   itself.

**In C++**:

The code is explained in the  `Angle` function below which is the last function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric> //for inner_product
#include <vector> //For vector
#include <math.h> //For sqrt, acos and M_PI

float Dot(std::vector<float> lhs, std::vector<float> rhs);
float magnitude(std::vector<float> vec3);
float Angle(std::vector<float> from, std::vector<float> to);
std::vector<float> normalise();

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> from{3, 1, -2};
    std::vector<float> to{5, -3, -7 };

    float angle = Angle(from,to);
    std::cout<<"Angle: "<<angle<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

//Find Dot/ Scalar product 
float Dot(std::vector<float> lhs, std::vector<float> rhs){
    return std::inner_product(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), 0);
}

//Find the magnitude of the Vector
float magnitude(std::vector<float> vec3)//<! Vector magnitude
{
   return sqrt((vec3[0] * vec3[0]) + (vec3[1] * vec3[1]) + (vec3[2] * vec3[2]));
}

//Normalize Vector. Not needed here
std::vector<float> normalise(std::vector<float> vect)  
{
    std::vector<float> temp{0, 0, 0};
    float length = magnitude(vect);

    temp[0] = vect[0]/length;
    temp[1] = vect[1]/length;
    temp[2] = vect[2]/length;
    return temp;
}

float Angle(std::vector<float> from, std::vector<float> to){
   //Find the scalar/dot product of the provided 2 Vectors
   float dotProduct = Dot(from, to);
   //Find the product of both magnitudes of the vectors then divide dot from it
   dotProduct = dotProduct / (magnitude(from) * magnitude(to));
   //Get the arc cosin of the angle, you now have your angle in radians 
   float arcAcos = acos(dotProduct);
   //Convert to degrees by Multiplying the arc cosin by 180/M_PI
   float angle = arcAcos * 180 / M_PI;
   return angle; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the Unity engine. This is a separate module I am creating to rig my own autoaim. I'm trying to do get the proper math itself.

Comment: It says "The game is Unity based" and it has unity tagged in it. You should make an edit in your question and include this there.

Comment: @Serlite Probably true but the document says "Returns the angle in degrees between from and to" which almost the-same as the question title and body.....

Comment: I think I could use this to just look at what Angle does and port it manually. This is useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @user6871291 Some good resources out there on the Stack Exchange network for that sort of thing - all you need to do is calculate magnitudes and the dot product: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654315/how-to-convert-a-dot-product-of-two-vectors-to-the-angle-between-the-vectors

Comment: @user6871291 Modified the answer. Included solution in C++ which finds the angle of to vectors.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks, but how can I convert this angle to Euler angles? I need a pitch / yaw / roll. I may be having a brain fart though, I am terrible with math.

Comment: To further add, I went inside the game itself, aimed the gun at my target's head and logged the (x,y,z) angles it gave me, these were my player's body angles:
`X: 3.719779 Y: -129.290237 Z: 0`

And these were the local coordinates at the time those Angles were logged.
`camera position = X -723.808655 Y: 3.997157 Z: 370.409210`
`enemy head =  X: -727.306885 Y: 2.18578 Z: 367.644775`

Comment: Despite plugging that data in, and trying to reproduce those specific angles or as close to those angles as possible, I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Take a look at the example I gave under Unity. It says "Or Individual angles" .  It shows how to get each axis individually. You can do  that with the C++ `Angle` function I provided too.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be producing the proper angles for me, at least not based on what the game produced. The game produced these angles `X: 3.719779 Y: -129.290237 Z: 0` The coordinates at the time those angles were logged. 
`camera position = X -723.808655 Y: 3.997157 Z: 370.409210` 
`enemy head = X: -727.306885 Y: 2.18578 Z: 367.644775`
I am plugging the numbers in, but am unable to reproduce the same or similar angles that the game itself produced when I logged them.

Comment: @user6871291: which direction is the camera oriented (i.e., pointed)?

Comment: @aichao: i did not record that but I did record the Body's rotation, which i guess can be kinda like camera direction? if that will help at all or if it means anything to you, its a Vector4 though `0.013898, -0.903197, 0.029329, 0.427998`

Comment: I believe I have to convert to to Euler Angles.

Comment: @user6871291: I would think that you need to rotate the `-diff` vector (from camera to enemy), which is in world coordinates, to the camera coordinates using the quaternion (i.e., the Vector4 you gave). Then compute `el = asin(y/sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z)*180/pi` and `az=atan2(x,z)` where `(x,y,z)` are the components of that rotated vector. However, this did not work out for me. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Unity to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the angle between two 3d coordinates, in degrees you can use this CalcAngle Function:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#define PI 3.1415927f

struct vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
}

vec3 Subtract(vec3 src, vec3 dst)
{
    vec3 diff;
    diff.x = src.x - dst.x;
    diff.y = src.y - dst.y;
    diff.z = src.z - dst.z;
    return diff;
}

float Magnitude(vec3 vec)
{
    return sqrtf(vec.x*vec.x + vec.y*vec.y + vec.z*vec.z);
}

float Distance(vec3 src, vec3 dst)
{
    vec3 diff = Subtract(src, dst);
    return Magnitude(diff);
}

vec3 CalcAngle(vec3 src, vec3 dst)
{
    vec3 angle;
    angle.x = -atan2f(dst.x - src.x, dst.y - src.y) / PI * 180.0f + 180.0f;
    angle.y = asinf((dst.z - src.z) / Distance(src, dst)) * 180.0f / PI;
    angle.z = 0.0f;

    return angle;
}
```

Complications:

Not all games use the same technique for angles and positions.  Min and Max values for x, y and z angles can be different in every game.  The basic idea is the same in all games, they just require minor modification to match each game.  For example, in the game the code was written for, the X value has to be made negative at the end for it to work.

Another complication is X, Y and Z don't always represent the same variables in both coordinates and angle vec3s.